# Twilio video doesn't showing up

Tags: javascript, html, video, twilio, twilio-api

I created html page for video between two users. I got audio stream and video stream:

```
<audio src="blob:file:///0f096ee4-d212-4e7a-a827-9a1a730f04cb" autoplay></audio>
<video src="blob:file:///127a03af-138c-484e-98cd-ec74a0fc10e4" autoplay></video>
```

It works when users are located in one town.
But if first user is located in Russia and second user is located in Finland, I got audio and video stream too, but we do not see or hear each other.
What could be the problem?

I attach logs:

[-1490185215256](http://sirpaul.ru/twilio/-1490185215256) (video and audio works good (first and second users are in Russia in the same town))

[-1490256777987](http://sirpaul.ru/twilio/-1490256777987) (connected, but video and audio doesn't work (first user is in Russia))

[-1490256766921](http://sirpaul.ru/twilio/-1490256766921) (connected, but video and audio doesn't work (second user is in Finland))

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console in this case?

Comment: No, I haven't error message. <audio> and <video> was added successfully, but I don't see user (he uses the same html file in Finland). It works if second user is located in the same town.

Comment: Can you try setting the `logLevel` to debug when you initialize the `Video.Client` and see if that says anything of use? https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta4/docs/Client.html

Comment: Try: `new Video.Client(accessToken, { logLevel: 'debug' });`

Comment: It looks like you don't have the Network Traversal Service enabled for your [configuration profile](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/profiles). Can you enable that and try again?

Comment: Go to the configuration profile for your Video service (link in previous comment) and check the checkbox for NTS there.

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid...

Comment: No worries! Let me know if that helps at all though

Comment: EU: 1MB $0.0004. Should I upgrade my trial account? Or it will works with my trial account without money?

Comment: I actually can't remember if NTS works with trial credit (I'm on a bus right now). You may need to upgrade your account. Try it without though, it might work.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works now. I upgraded my account and enabled Network Traversal Service

Comment: Sweet! Glad to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded my account and turned on Network Traversal Service.
It didn't work because I used trial account without Network Traversal Service.